# Elasticsearch NEST Document count for default index

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST for Elasticsearch 6 and would like to get the number of documents for the default index.

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/count.html) refers to the 1.1 version of the API which no longer seems to work.

I have created the connection settings using a default index:

```
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings().DefaultIndex("test_docs");
```

When I try the code from the 1.1 api documentation:

```
var result = client.Count();
```

I get the following error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'ElasticClient.Count(Func, ICountRequest>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

When I supply a type it is appended to the path.  For example:

```
client.Count<TestDocument>();
```

Generates a URL of http://localhost:9200/test_docs/testdocument/_count when what I really need is http://localhost:9200/test_docs/_count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
var countResponse = client.Count<TestDocument>(c => c.AllTypes());
```

which will call the API

```
GET http://localhost:9200/test_docs/_count
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I didn't realise I needed to include AllTypes

Comment: c.AllTypes() is missing

Answer (score 4):

For those needing the new way of doing this (like myself). I would use the following to get a count from a specific index.

```
var countRequest = new CountRequest(Indices.Index("videos"));
long count = (await _ecClient.CountAsync(countRequest)).Count;
```